# Could you please solve this system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

x + y = 0

-x + z = 0

-2x - 3y - z = 0

I’ve tried substitution and I arrive at x, y, z, all equal 0. But I checked the solution (it’s for a physics sum) and it says x = 1, y = -1, z = 1, which also holds. But I can’t find any way to arrive at this.

Could you please help me out? Thank you!

Comment: Please show us your work that lead you to $x = y = z = 0$, There is probably some mistake in there.

Comment: So I found x = -y and x = z. Thus -y = z. I put this in the third equation  leading it to be 2y - 3y + y = 0, thus y = 0. Which implies z = 0 and thus x = 0. The same happens if I substitute y with z in equation 3, @JonathanZ supports MonicaC.

Comment: $ 2y - 3y + y = 0$ reduces to $0 = 0$, not $y = 0$. And by the way, this system of equations has an infinite number of solutions. Do you know how to handle that?

Comment: Also, if your solution set says that __the__ solution is (1,-1,1), it is straight up mathematically wrong. It is __a__ solution, but not the only solution. Are you 100% sure that all your equations end with "$= 0$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add $x + y = 0$ to $-x + z = 0$ and add $x + y = 0$ twice to the third equation, you get the following new set of equations:

$$x + y = 0$$
$$y + z = 0$$
$$-y - z = 0$$

Notice that the last equation is redundant and can be removed. This means the system has an infinite set of solutions. (0, 0, 0) happens to be one of those solutions. (In fact, all systems where the right side is all zeroes have this as a solution.)

If we then subtract $y + z = 0$ from $x + y = 0$, we get:

$$x - z = 0$$
$$y + z = 0$$

z is a free variable meaning it can take any value. Solving for $x$ and $y$ tells us that $x = z$ and $y = -z$ for all $z$. So if we choose $z = 1$, we get what the textbook said was the answer.